# How to extend wave in cooledit so it will be 5 sec long insted of 3

Tags: audio, sound-effects, sound-design, sound

I have a small sound effect that plays for 3 seconds, and I need it to last for 5 seconds (I know this could modify the sound pitch, im ok with that).

**Is there a way to do this on cooledit?** I was expecting to just select the wave and "extend" it with some mouse control but that doesnt exist and i cant find any way to achieve what I need.

Comment: Isn't Cooledit is Adobe Audition now?

Comment: Yes it is, Adobe bought CoolEdit

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am using the updated version (Adobe Audition) but many of these features remain in Cool Edit Pro. For this, I would use the "Stretch and Pitch" process. Select what you're trying to extend, and go to the "Effects" menu (may have a different title for you). Select "Stretch and Pitch" under the "Time and Pitch" category.

There, you will have several options as to how you plan on stretching the audio. One option you will have is whether or not to maintain the pitch. If you choose to maintain the current pitch, the audio might have a distorted quality. If you select the opposite, the distorted quality won't be nearly as bad, but the pitch will most definitely change. This is simply a matter of preference.